# passing List and String data from ajax to controller in mvc 4, getting NULL for list?

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Hi I'm new to JavaScript and MVC, and I'm trying to pass List and string to my controller.

JavaScript looks like:

```
 var parms = {
                  globalList: globalList,
                  fieldName: fieldName
              };
              $.ajax({
                  //contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                  type: "POST",
                  traditional: true,
                  url: "/Home/SaveField",
                  async: false,
                  data: parms,
                  dataType: "json",
                  success: function (data) {
                      console.log("uspjeh");
                  },
                  error: function (errorData) {
                      console.log("errors");
                  }

              });
          });
```

and controller looks like:

```
public void SaveField(List<Point> globalList, String fieldName)
{
  // filedName is correctly passed
  // list is null
}
```

can somebody help me please?

Point class:

```
public class Point
{
  [Key]
  public int PointId { get; set; }
  public float GeoDuzina { get; set; }
  public float GeoSirina { get; set; }
  [ForeignKey("Data")]
  public int DataId { get; set; }
  public virtual Data Data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: where do you get globalList in your JS code ??

Comment: globalList is a list of coordinates from mapbox, they are correct I checkt it                                                        {"globalList": [{"GeoDuzina":51.506760996586294,"GeoSirina":-0.06106463202740998},{"GeoDuzina":51.516269286402846,"GeoSirina":-0.056258113472722464},{"GeoDuzina":51.50419662363912,"GeoSirina":-0.044413478462956846}]}

Comment: Show the `Point` class

Comment: What object did you just post in the comments? If that is supposed to be the `globalList` variable in your javascript code, then you have one nesting too much, it would look like this: `{globalList: { globalList: [..content..] } }`

Comment: @user3906678....just change float to double datatype of properties...

Comment: I tried changing it to double.. didn't work! And yes it is my globalList, how should I change it to work?

Answer (score 0):

It wont work. If you debug a little then you will see that you post to server something like this:

```
globalList:[object Object]
globalList:[object Object]
globalList:[object Object]
```

It is just array of strings. But there is a way to do what you want.
You can serialize your array to json and then deserialize it in your controller. Just change your param to:

```
var parms = {
    globalList: JSON.stringify(globalList),
    fieldName: fieldName
};
```

And action:

```
[HttpPost]
public void SaveField(string globalList, string fieldName)
{
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer(); //use any serializer you want
    var list = serializer.Deserialize<List<Point>>(globalList);
}
```

Or you can make param object looks like from HTML form:

```
var parms = {
     "globalList[0].GeoDuzina": 51.506760996586294, 
     "globalList[0].GeoSirina": -0.06106463202740998,
     "globalList[1].GeoDuzina": 51.516269286402846, 
     "globalList[1].GeoSirina": -0.056258113472722464,
     "globalList[2].GeoDuzina": 51.50419662363912, 
     "globalList[2].GeoSirina": -0.044413478462956846,
     fieldName: fieldName
 };
```

It works with your action.

There are many other ways to do that. I just show two of them. Is any good for you?

btw. This numbers are too long for floats.;)