# List passed to controller via AJAX is null

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to pass a `List` of `objects` back to my `controller`, but the `List` is `null` if/when it gets to the `controller`.  Here is what I'm doing:

Controller Action Signature

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult SaveSpec(IEnumerable<DpvItemLiteVm> alarms){}
```

View Model

```
public class DpvItemLiteVm
    {
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string Program { get; set; }
        public string DeviceType { get; set; }
        public string PartName { get; set; }
        public string RoutineId { get; set; }
        public string FtrName { get; set; }
        public string FtrAttCode { get; set; }
        public decimal LowVal { get; set; }
        public decimal HiVal { get; set; }
        public decimal? TargetVal { get; set; }
    }
```

And the View

```
var alarms = [];

$('#featureSpecGrid tr').each(function () {
     var $tds = $(this).find('td');
     var target = $tds.eq(4).text() === '' ? null : parseFloat($tds.eq(4).text());
     var temp = {
          Location: location,
          Program: program,
          DeviceType: device,
          PartName: part,
          RoutineId: routine,
          FtrName: $tds.eq(0).text(),
          FtrAttCode: $tds.eq(1).text(),
          LowVal: parseFloat($tds.eq(2).text()),
          HiVal: parseFloat($tds.eq(3).text()),
          TargetVal: target
     };
     alarms.push(temp);
});

//alarms = JSON.stringify({ 'alarms': alarms });

//console.log(alarms);

$.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     cache: false,
     contentType: 'application/json',
     url: '/Dpv/SaveSpec',
     data: alarms
}).done(function (partialViewResult) {
     $('#statusMsg').html(partialViewResult);
}).always(function(result) {
     console.log(result);
});
```

I've tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242414/passing-a-list-of-objects-into-an-mvc-controller-method-using-jquery-ajax), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25119281/passing-list-and-string-data-from-ajax-to-controller-in-mvc-4-getting-null-for), and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16547491/ajax-post-to-asp-net-mvc-controller-object-properties-are-null) (to name a few); if I use `JSON.stringify` (as some of the answers suggest) I get a `404` response.  I've also tried using a `List` instead of `IEnumerable`, making my `View Model` smaller (location, program, device, part, and routine are the same for each item being passed back) and setting up the AJAX accordingly (returns a `404` error).  If I do manage to make it back to the `controller`, the `List` is `null`.

Here's a sample of the payload if I `stringify` it: 
`{"alarms":"Location":"ABC123","Program":"1A2B","DeviceType":"Device","PartName":"Part1","RoutineId":"ABC456","FtrName":"Feature1","FtrAttCode":"CodeA","LowVal":-1.01,"HiVal":1.01,"TargetVal":null}`

And if I don't `stringify`:

`[object Array]
     0
         Location:"ABC123"
         Program:"1A2B"
         DeviceType:"Device"
         PartName:"Part1"
         RoutineId:"ABC456"
         FtrName:"Feature1"
         FtrAttCode:"CodeA"
         LowVal:-1.01
         HiVal:1.01
         TargetVal":null
     1`

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `contentType: 'application/json'`, you need to send data as the JSON string so that model binder will be able to map it.

You should be sending complex data via **`POST`** method, not GET. GET method is fine for sending small lean-flat view model with few properties. These will be send as query string by the `$.ajax` method. In your case, your data is not a flat-lean view model. So you should use POST as the method so that `$.ajax` will send the data in request body.

I also recommend you to use the `Url.Action` helper method to generate the correct relative url to the action method.

```
var urlToSave="@Url.Action("SaveSpec","Dpv")";
// use urlToSavefor the ajax call 

$.ajax({
     type: 'POST',       
     contentType: 'application/json',
     url: urlToSave,
     data: JSON.stringify(alarms)
}).done(function (partialViewResult) {
     $('#statusMsg').html(partialViewResult);
}).always(function(result) {
     console.log(result);
});
```

Also make sure your aciton method is POST

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveSpec(IEnumerable<DpvItemLiteVm> alarms)
{
    // to do : return something
}
```

Now the model binder will be able to read the request body and map it to the `IEnumerable<DpvItemLiteVm>` parameter you have.

Comment: This is what I needed; works like a charm now.  That's good to know about `POST`; I've always used `@using(Html.BeginForm(){}` to pass large amounts of data back to the controller for processing, but I'm adding to an existing code base and using a `form` would have been much more difficult to get it to work.  Thanks for the help!